# How do I design a REST interface that allows for updating the sort order of a list of related items?

Tags: rest, sorting, post, many-to-many

Assuming I want to develop a client application that manages playlists of songs and has the following objects stored on the server:

- Playlist { title:unique }
- PlaylistSong { PlaylistId, SongId, sortOrder }
- Song { title:unique }

How could I design a REST interface so that the order of a playlist can be changed from the client, and that a new song could be entered into an existing playlist at a specific position.
In other words, I do not know what the REST interface would look like in order to implement the following two actions:

- Add song to playlist in   specific location
- Update the order of the   playlist

The basic set of actions I want to implement, I understand should look like this:

```
User action:           Rest Resource

Create playlist:       POST /playlist
Get Playlist:          GET /playlist/{id}
Get Playlist Songs:    GET /playlist/{id}/songs
Create song:           POST /song
Update song:           PUT /song
Get song:              GET /song/{id}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use PUT to change the order of the songs on the playlist:

```
GET /playlist/{id}/songs
{
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "self" : "http://my.server/song/1",
        "name" : "The Little Old Lady From Pasadena"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "self" : "http://my.server/song/2",
        "name" : "Love Potion #9"
    }
}

PUT /playlist/{id}/songs
{
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "self" : "http://my.server/song/2",
        "name" : "Love Potion #9"
    },
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "self" : "http://my.server/song/1",
        "name" : "The Little Old Lady From Pasadena"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the nice example. I will try something like this and let you know how it works out.